# Construction of a codimension 1 dense subspace without Zorn

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, axiom-of-choice, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose $X$ is an infinite dimensional topological vector space 
and  $v\in X$ is non-zero. It is then not difficult to construct 
a vector space $U\subset X$ so that

1)  $U$ is dense in $X$.

2) $U+{\mathbb C} v = X$.

In particular $U$ has co-dimension 1 in $X$ but is not closed.

Now, proofs that I can think of uses Zorn: Consider/construct a
dense subspace $V$ not containing $v$ (usually not so difficult)
and consider the collection of subspaces containing $V$ but not $v$,
partially ordered under inclusion. If a vector $w\in X\setminus (V+{\mathbb C} v)$ you may add it to $V$ to get a larger such space.
It is strictly inductively ordered so a maximal element $U$ will
do the job.

The catch is that this is not very 'visual'. I can not give
an explicit description of any such maximal element.
So my question is if there is an explicit way to construct such a $U$
without resorting to Zorn/Axiom of Choice?

If possible, best would be an example with $X$ a separable Banach/Hilbert space.

Comment: Even easier, by the way, is to begin by extending $\{v\}$ to a basis, then considering the part of that basis which is not $v$ itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are asking for a discontinuous linear functional that is non zero at $v$, but it is consistent with $ZF$ that every linear functional on a Banach space is continuous.  However, on some normed spaces you can do what you want in $ZF$. For example, take $X:=c_{00}$, the space of finitely non zero real sequences under the sup norm.  Given $0\not= v$ in $X$, you can explicitly construct an element $u$   in $\ell_2 \sim \ell_1$ s.t.  $\langle u, v\rangle =1$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand the first part correctly, there is no complete normed space where I can get such an example without Zorn? Without completion I could simply take some $U$ dense in a Banach space $Y$, pick a vector $v \in Y\setminus U$ and let $X=U + {\mathbb C} v$ but the example is a bit trivial. Any reference for the ZF continuity?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh: You can find it in Schechter's book about foundation of functional analysis, whose exact name escapes me. Also in papers by Wright, Garnir and a few others.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh There is no *constructive* Banach example without Zorn. This is also discussed on StackExchange [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99206/discontinuous-linear-functional).